# Change behavior of button using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to figure out how to change behaviour of a button using AJAX.

When the button is clicked, it means that `user` confirmed order recently created. `AJAX` calls `/confirm-order/<id>` and if the `order` has been confirmed, I want to change the button to redirect to `/my-orders/` after next click on it. The problem is that it calls again the same `JQuery` function. I've tried already to remove `class="confirm-button"` attribute to avoid `JQuery` again but it does not work. What should I do?

It would be enough, if the button has been removed and replaced by text "Confirmed", but this.html() changes only inner html which is a text of the button.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".confirm-button").click(function (b) {
            b.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);
            var id = this.value;
            var url = '/confirm-order/'+id;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    $this.empty();
                    $this.attr('href','/my-orders/');
                    $this.parent().attr("action", "/my-orders/");
                    $this.html('Confirmed');
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event handler will be still attached to the button, so this will run again:

```
b.preventDefault();
```

which will prevent the default, which is opening the `href`. You need to remove the event handler on success. You use the jQuery `#off()` method:

```
$(".confirm-button").off('click');
```

or more shortly:

```
$this.off('click');
```

Comment: Hello, that's the problem, I can't figure out how to remove the handler on success.

Answer (score 1):

You can add to your `success` function something like: `$this.data('isConfirmed', true);`

And then in your click handler start by checking for it. If it's true, redirect the user to the next page.

```
$(".confirm-button").click(function (b) {
    b.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.data('isConfirmed')) {
        ... redirect code ...
    }
    else {
        ... your regular code ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.on()` rather than `.click()` to catch events after the document is ready, because the "new" button appears later.

See http://api.jquery.com/on/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-confirm').click(function(){
    alert('Confirmed!');
    $(this).off('click').removeClass('js-confirm').addClass('js-redirect').html('Redirect');
  });
  
  $(document).on('click', '.js-redirect', function(){
    alert('Redirecting');
  });
});
```

```html
<button class="js-confirm">Confirm</button>
```